# Does Truecrypt limits the number of standard volumes inside an outer volume when creating an hidden volume

Tags: truecrypt, logical-drive

I´ve been trying to use Truecrypt as to create 3 standard encrypted volumes/containers and an hidden volume, all 4 inside a single outer volume.

When using the Truecrypt wizard I and selecting the Hidden Volume option, I can then create the outer volume, the 2 first standard volumes but when I am creating the third one (just before creating the hidden volume) it just fails at about 75% of the formatting.

The same error always appears on the screen telling me that the volume (the third one that I am intending to create) is busy.

I have restarted my computer and tried it many times but without any success, am I trying to do something which is not possible or is there another better way to do it?

Comment: I just thought inbetween that it could be because of the size of the 3rd volume/container that I am trying to create as I wanted it to be 5 GB big, I also tried with 4 GB (as there seems to be a distinction with the maximum file size when creating volumes in Truecrypt) but it also fails except that this time it fails at the end of the fomatting (actually 100% of it but still not working). Any ideas?